# Detect IFormatProvider or CultureInfo from String using VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, format, cultureinfo

*Well*, for avoiding `Format Exceptions` in a `Convert.ToDecimal`, `ToSingle`, and `ToDouble`, I use a `Foreach` with an array of `CultureInfo` class, but, is there a method for detecting which are the "possible cultures" from a string? (I say possible cultures because some culture shares their format.)

An **example**: If I use "1,080.47" I want to return `en-US`, and if I use "1.080,47" I want to return `fr-FR`, `es-ES`, etc.

*What do you recommend?*

Comment: Sorry! ^^ (I forgot it)

Comment: under what conditions would an `en-US` app be presented with a `fr-FR` decimal value? (Trying to head off an XY round robin...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same numeric formatting can pertains to various cultures, so maybe I'm wrong but I'll imagine that the best you could do is match the valid cultures for an specific format and then use your own logic to decide, something like this which is only an example for *Single*:

```
Public Function MatchCultures(ByVal str As String) as list(of string)

    Dim ValidCultures As New List(Of String)

    Dim CultureNames As IEnumerable(Of String) =
        From cultureInfo In cultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
        Select cultureInfo.Name

    For Each CultureName As String In CultureNames

        Try

            Convert.ToSingle(str, New CultureInfo(CultureName))
            ValidCultures.Add(CultureName)

        Catch ex As FormatException
            ' Do nothing

        End Try

    Next

    Return ValidCultures

End Function
```

Also you could speed-up the procedure if you want to limit the CultureNames to a specific range lets say { "en-Us", "fr", "es", etc... } 'cause the list of culture-names is too big: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/goglobal/bb896001.aspx

Anyways I think that you're approaching the problem into a bad solution, you should use the "TryParse" helper methods from datatypes like:

```
If Single.TryParse("1.000", New Single) Then...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, and I'll quote [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture(v=vs.110).aspx)

> *In the .NET Framework *4* and *previous versions*, by default, the culture of all threads is set to the Windows system culture*

However, there's a distinction between input and output. I'll start with the trivial part.

**Output**

This is the easy one. *We're* in control. If the user wants a `,` as a decimal separator , so shall be done.

```
decimalValue.ToString(123.456, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nb-NO"))
```

Output:

> 123,456

**Input**

This is the tricky part. I'm a Norwegian (as I guess you've figured out), and yes, we use the comma (`,`) as a decimal separator. Does this mean that all my fellows will input `,` instead of `.`? **No**. So applies to dates. Some users input *dd-MM-yyyy* "instead" of *dd.MM.yyyy*. Welcome to the [*UXD*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience_design). However (and this might not be true for others), I'm yet to see a user trying to input a `thousand separator` when working with floating numbers.

---

**Conclusion**

My best advice is to use the default Culture Info as the **output**, and as implied, format the user **input** if not valid.

**Note**

FYI, the Culture Info reveals many a useful properties. Here's a few related to my anwwer:

- CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator
- CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator